# Angular - edit and export table to pdf

Tags: python, angular, pdf, jspdf, pypdf

I cannot figure out pdf reports creation.

**Problem** : how to edit a table exported from excel - I have to keep the formating, colors etc - as it would be a picture.

2. I've tried:

   - (at frontend) **export table from excel to html** and edit it with Angular - no problems with interpolation, but while exporting it with jspdf - **as text**, it gives only text and loses all the formating; **as an image** - it loses resolution and pixelizes.
   - (at backend) **export table to pdf** - looks as it should, can contatenate it with other pdfs to create a report easily but the only way I found to fill the cells is to use x, y coordinates with pypdf and reportlab which is a pain to do and one-way ticket if I'll have to change the table in the future.
     I hope it is readable and you'll got the point.

Have a look at this prototype to get the idea:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/pdfreportexporter

Comment: What Excel format do you use? (i.e. which Excel version are you intending to support?)

Comment: It seems that you are actually addressing a tool chain, please describe it in more detail and add the actual end format (I guess PDF) as well.

Comment: If it matters somehow I used 2016 (.xlsb) to export, but my goal is to fill the cells in a webpage and export a report to pdf, not using Excel.

Comment: So your actual question is to export a HTML table to PDF? In this case I'd highly recommend to remove all concerning Excel here and add the details really important to solve the issue. (this looks to me like an informative "detail": *`my goal is to fill the cells in a webpage and export a report to pdf`*)

Comment: As I don't know the answer, I probably don't know how to ask the proper question. The starting point is the excel table, which could be converted to html, xml, pdf etc, and the end is the filled table exported to pdf. What I need is a method or toolchain to do that.